# What's the difference between fromCallable and defer?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

`fromCallable` and `defer` have different implementation. I heard some say that `defer` helps with recursion but i can't produce any code that shows the difference between them.

i tried with infinite number implementation:

```
private Observable<Integer> numbers(int start) {
         return Observable.just(start)
                .concatWith(Observable.defer(() -> numbers(start + 1)));
    }
```

but i still get stack overflow exception when subscribing

Comment: https://artemzin.com/blog/rxjava-defer-execution-of-function-via-fromcallable/

Comment: `fromCallable` is kinda a convenient method for `Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(value))`

Answer (score 17):

`fromCallable` creates observable that emits single value, then completes.

`defer` postpones creation of actual observable until it is subscribed to. So you can create *multi-value* observable based on state at time of subscription. For example:

```
Observable<Integer> daysOfWeekLeft =
    Observable.defer(() -> 
        Observable.range(currentDayOfWeek(), 7 - currentDayOfWeek()));
```

Basically you can achieve the same with `fromCallable` like this:

```
Observable<Integer> daysOfWeekLeft =
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> currentDayOfWeek())
        .flatMap(day -> Observable.range(day, 7 - day));
```

PS. Your code for infinite stream of numbers results in infinite recursion. Might need to play with schedulers to avoid that.

Comment: why does `defer` emits multiple values?

Comment: @Dennis because author write this.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at it terms of `Single`, which is less complicated than Observable, because it can only have 1 value. (i.e. An observable with 1 emission). The following applies to the other types as well (Observable, Flowable, Completable)

### `Single.fromCallable`

`Single.fromCallable` actually creates a new Single from the value inside the function it calls. This is why Aaron He said is comment:

> fromCallable is kinda a convenient method for Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(value))

It does that extra step of creating an Observable by using `.just`. If you call a function `fromCallable` which already creates a Single, you'll get a nested single.

```kotlin
// Not very useful to get a Single<Single<*>>
val fromCallable: Single<Single<String>> = Single.fromCallable {
    Single.just("Example")
}

// Better in these cases, where the function inside doesn't create a Single already:
 fun heavyFunction(): String { return "Heavy" }
val fromCallable2: Single<String> = Single.fromCallable {heavyFunction()}
```

### `Single.defer`

`Single.defer` calls the function inside it, if it returns a Single, then you can use that Single later on. If it doesn't, it won't compile.

```kotlin
val defer: Single<String> = Single.defer {
    Single.just("Example")
}

// This line won't compile:
Single.defer {heavyFunction()}

// You need to wrap it in a Single:
val defer2: Single<String> = Single.defer {Single.just(heavyFunction())}
```

---

So, Single.fromCallable creates a Single **from** a **callable**, hence the name. This callable that doesn't have to create a Single, it can be anything.

Defer doesn't create a **new** Single, it just calls its body which should create a Single. That's why it doesn't have the `from` in its function name.